# discord.py simplify code with function doesn´t work

Tags: python, function, discord, discord.py, replit

I´m programming a discord bot, that allows admins to change the server nicknames of the other members. If the bot doesn´t have the permission to change the name (e.g. the onces from admins) it dms it to you. If this isn´t possible it sends a message in the same textchannel the admin wrote the change-nickname-command. It worked perfektly but now i want to simplify my code and put the thing in a function, but this doesn´t work.

```
async def dm(user_id, dm_content, server_content, channel):
    user = await bot.fetch_user(user_id)
    try:
        await user.send(dm_content)
    except discord.Forbidden:
        await channel.send(server_content)
    return


async def on_message(msg):
***something else (e.g. the if statement for the permission check)***
await dm(msg.author.id, "I dont´t have the permission to change this nickname!", "I dont´t have the permission to change this nickname! (I wasn´t able to dm you, please check your privacysettings)", msg.channel)
```

Error message: 'msg' is not defined
how do i define msg or how do i get the function to work?
thanks

Comment: Did you use the correct decorators, such as `bot.listener()` as well? Also make sure to set it to `msg: discord.Message` just to avoide possible errors.

Comment: Great to hear. Just posted this as an answer again, just in case if there are more users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function looks correct to me. Just make sure to use the actual arguments for the event or use proper definitions.

The following code should get rid of the `'msg' is not defined` error:

```py
@bot.event()
async def on_message(msg: discord.Message):
```

Make sure to always define the arguments used to avoid any possible errors.